# issue with for loop in python only gets the last item

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iteration, enumerate

I'm a beginner in python, currently I'm trying to automate filling website field using `selenium`.

I'm trying to iterate over nested lists using `for` loop but always get only the last element. Any suggestions why?

```py
fields = [['a','b','c'],['x','y','z']]
for i in range(len(fields)):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("element").send_keys(fields[i][0],fields[i[1],fields[i][2])
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("element_save").click()

#then loop and iterate through 2nd nested list

# OUTPUT = x,y,z
```

I expect to iterate starting with index 0 to the end of the list.

Comment: Why are you using `enumerate` if you aren't using `v` (which you *could* use in place of `fields[i]` in the body)?

Comment: (And if you *do* use `v`, you don't need `i`, again calling into question the need for `enumerate`.)

Comment: Your loop does output:

`a,b,c`
then
`x,y,z` 

right? What is the expected output then?

Comment: it gets only the elements of the last nested list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `range(len(list_))` for iterating over indeces only.

Usual `for` will do. You can also unpack list with `*`:

```py
fields = [['a','b','c'],['x','y','z']]
len_ = len(fields)
for i in range(len_):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("element").send_keys(*fields[i])
```

You could also iterate trhrough the values of the `fields` itself:

```py
fields = [['a','b','c'],['x','y','z']]

for field in fields:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("element").send_keys(*field)
```

Comment: I have tried that but it also goes to the last element. Im using Keys.TAB to move between fields. will i be able to use *?

Comment: `*` will unpack whatever elements are in the list.

Comment: Are you talking about going to the XPath element?

Comment: `driver` always goes to the last element, because it's hardcoded. You iterate only over the `fields`. Meaning the keys you are sending. If you want to iterate over elements one more loop is needed.

Comment: when driver goes to the page to be filled, it gets filled with items from the last nested list. I'm expecting it to fill the page with items of the first nested list then save and open this page again and fill fields with items from  2nd nested list then etc.

Comment: Oh. That's completely different behavior from what you have written in the script. 
You have to include in the `for` loop all the actions you want to repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there is a bug in your program as you have written it:

```py
fields = [['a','b','c'],['x','y','z']]
for i, v in enumerate(fields):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("element").send_keys(fields[i][0],fields[i[1],fields[i][2])
                                                                           ^ # No closing ]
```

Secondly there is a term that Python developers like to throw around: [Pythonic Code](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/style/).

We like to write short concise code that favors readability over squeezing every last inch of performance.

Referring to this you should change your code as it is unnecessarily cluttered and you are not even utilizing the `value` element of `enumerate`. I would recommend the following:

```py
fields = [['a','b','c'],['x','y','z']]
for field in fields:
    name, age, height = field  # Replace this line with whatever the fields represent
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("element").send_keys(name, age, height)
```

This code is short, concise, and above all extremely readable to someone else.

Note: Replace the `name`, `age`, `height` with whatever they represent in your program.

If in fact this didn't solve your problem, your problem may not be with python but with selenium itself and that is out of the scope of this question. You can test this with simply printing the values before feeding it to the selenium function like this:

```py
fields = [['a','b','c'],['x','y','z']]
for field in fields:
    name, age, height = field  # Replace this line with whatever the fields represent
    print(name, age, height)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("element").send_keys(name, age, height)
```

Hope this helps.